# Can't set textview value inside InfoWindowAdapter

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to create a Custom infowindow with the following code.

Inside activity:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
private final View contents = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow, null);

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
         return null;
               }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        TextView txtTitle = ((TextView) contents.findViewById(R.id.txtInfoWindowTitle));
        txtTitle.setText("teste");
        return contents;
                    }
                });
```

The infowindow is created for all markers and the layout file is correct, but the txtInfoWindowTitle is always empty, even with a default value defined in infowindow.xml layout file

the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInfoWindowTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="primeira linha"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/txtInfoWindowClick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ff7f7f7f"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:text="toque para abrir a ficha" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried simplifying your layout for debugging, getting rid of things like the `gravity` and `layout_gravity` attributes, to see if somehow those are a problem? Debugging info windows is a pain, since the views get flattened into a bitmap. You might also consider setting a background color on the `TextView`, again for debugging purposes.

Comment: Cleaning the layout file solve the problem... now I style it inside `getInfoContents()`. Do you have any idea why does it happen?

Answer (score 3):

This code works fine for me

```
View contents;

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    if(contents==null) {
        contents = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(
                        R.layout.info_content,
                        null);
    }
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) contents.findViewById(R.id.txtInfoWindowTitle);
    txtTitle.setText("teste");
        return contents;
    }
```

It's your LinearLayout inside another layout?

Comment: I'm using your code now but what really solved the problem was cleaning the layout file (don't know why). The LinearLayout is the root of the file...